# Cannot build Unity project from command line on fresh git cloned repository

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am looking to build Unity project just after git cloning them. However when they are "fresh" (only not giignored files) the build is very short and has no output. I have to open once the project with Unity Editor to make the build command line working.

Build command line:

```
 D:/------/Unity.exe -quit -batchmode -logFile uniytBuildLog.txt -buildTarget Win64 -executeMethod AutoBuilder.PerformBuild -appName test.exe -buildFolder "./Build/"
```

End of build log that seems to be a succes despite a strange error

```
Reloading assemblies after script compilation.
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
Refreshing native plugins compatible for Editor in 3.09 ms, found 7 plugins.
Preloading 2 native plugins for Editor in 0.15 ms.
Mono: successfully reloaded assembly
Refreshing native plugins compatible for Editor in 0.79 ms, found 7 plugins.
Preloading 2 native plugins for Editor in 0.11 ms.

----- Total AssetImport time: 0.130863s, AssetImport time: 0.000000s, Asset hashing: 0.000000s [0 B, 0.000000 mb/s]

- Completed reload, in  1.564 seconds
Initializing Unity.PackageManager (PackageManager) v2017.2.1 for Unity v2017.2.1f1
Registering platform support modules:
Registered platform support modules in: 0.0496396s.
Native extension for OSXStandalone target not found
Native extension for WindowsStandalone target not found
Native extension for LinuxStandalone target not found
Native extension for WebGL target not found
Native extension for Metro target not found
Native extension for iOS target not found
Native extension for Android target not found
Batchmode quit successfully invoked - shutting down!
Refresh: detecting if any assets need to be imported or removed ... Refresh: elapses 0.046037 seconds (Nothing changed)
Updating ProjectSettings/ProjectSettings.asset - GUID: 00000000000000004000000000000000...
 done. [Time: 61.503121 ms] 
Refreshing native plugins compatible for Editor in 1.32 ms, found 7 plugins.
Preloading 2 native plugins for Editor in 0.12 ms.

----- Total AssetImport time: 0.196505s, AssetImport time: 0.107053s, Asset hashing: 0.000000s [0 B, 0.000000 mb/s]

Refresh: detecting if any assets need to be imported or removed ... Refresh: elapses 0.032108 seconds (Nothing changed)
[Package Manager] Server::Kill -- Server was shutdown
Cleanup mono
[usbmuxd] Stop listen thread
[usbmuxd] Listen thread exiting
Exiting batchmode successfully now!

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Directory 'C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\160279e2' not found.

  at System.IO.Directory.GetFileSystemEntries (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, FileAttributes mask, FileAttributes attrs) [0x000f7] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:514 

  at System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories (System.String path, System.String searchPattern) [0x00000] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:275 

  at System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories (System.String path) [0x00000] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:270 

  at System.IO.Directory.RecursiveDelete (System.String path) [0x00000] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:186 

  at System.IO.Directory.Delete (System.String path, Boolean recursive) [0x0000c] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:205 

  at System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection.Delete () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection.Dispose (Boolean disposing) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection.Finalize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
debugger-agent: Unable to listen on 3896
```

Comment: so if you open the editor than the build works afterwards? maybe because the editor needs to regenerate the files that aren't added to the repository

Comment: Yes this is the case but is there any solution to regenerate the project from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problem was due to the lack of the argument with the project path.

I was thinking that skipping this argument would use the project in the current directory but it uses instead the last opened project so it was not building the right one until I open it with the Editor.

Comment: For anyone else who ends up here in suffering trying to get Unity to build in a CI/CD pipeline off of fresh clones/compiles every run, setting the `-buildTarget` param in the CLI was the trick for me. Editor was attempting to open an Android branch but targeting standalone by default, so it wouldn't compile and had a bunch of strange and irrelevant errors being thrown.